# WatiN: When finding text, how do I get a reference to its containing element?

Tags: c#, watin

Given the following HTML page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>WatiN Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to be able to search for some text (lets say `"World"`), and get a reference to its parent element (in this case the `<p>` element).

---

If I try this:

```
var element = ie.Element(Find.ByText(t => t.Contains("World")))
```

or this:

```
var element = ie.Element(e => e.Text != null && e.Text.Contains("World"));
```

I get back the `<html>` element. This is consistent with the WatiN documentation for `Element.Text` which states: *"Gets the innertext of this element (and the innertext of all the elements contained in this element)".*

Since all text within the page is contained within the `<html>` element, I'll always get this back instead of the immediate parent.

---

Is there a way to get just the text immediately beneath an element (not the text within the elements contained by it)?

Is there another way of doing this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bellow code will find first element inside the `<body/>` with text containing "World". Elements which are classified as element containers and has child elements will be omitted.

```
var element = ie.ElementOfType<Body>(Find.First()).Element(e =>
{
    if (e.Text != null && e.Text.Contains("World"))
    {
        var container = e as IElementContainer;
        if (container == null || container.Elements.Count == 0)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

*Note*: You may wonder why I wrote `ie.ElementOfType<Body>(Find.First()).Element` instead of just `ie.Element`. This should work, but it doesn't. I think it's a bug. I wrote a post about it on WatiN mailing list and will update this answer when I receive the answer.

Comment: Nice solution, thanks! I would actually need it to work if the HTML was modified to be `<p><strong>Hello</strong> World!</p>` but I didn't state that in the question, so this answer is correct. It's only fair that I mark it as the accepted answer for now. :)

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it later, but at I think this answer is a good starter to something bigger ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could use Find.BySelector

```
var element = ie.Element(Find.BySelector("p:contains('World')"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with something that works, but it's a bit hacky and very inefficient.

This essentially works on the basis that the deepest containing element will have the shortest `InnerHtml`. That is, all other elements which contain the immediate parent will include it's HTML as well, and therefore be longer!

```
public static Element FindElementContaining(IElementsContainer ie, string text)
{
    Element matchingElement = null;

    foreach (Element element in ie.Elements)
    {
        if (element.Text == null) continue;

        if (!element.Text.ToLower().Contains(text.ToLower())) continue;

        // If the element found has more inner html than the one we've already matched, it can't be the immediate parent!
        if (matchingElement != null && element.InnerHtml.Length > matchingElement.InnerHtml.Length) continue;

        matchingElement = element;
    }

    return matchingElement;
}
```