# How to find id's which ends with Watin

Tags: c#, browser, watin

How could i found elements by id in a html document using Watin. For example:

```
 browser.Link(Find.ById(string+"abc"));
```

Is is possible ?

Later edit:

I found this and seems to work

```
browser.Element(wat.Find.BySelector("a:contains('pdf')")).ClickNoWait();
```

now ... how can i add to list every element which contains 'pdf' ?

Comment: Have a look at this link it might answer your query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736111/watin-when-finding-text-how-do-i-get-a-reference-to-its-containing-element

Comment: @HatSoft thanks for the answer but it doesn't because i need to find all the elements as a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like that will work but I haven't tested it. It will probably be quite slow, but you can change the ElementCollection to something else. The `if` clause could be improved too.

```
ElementCollection elc = ie.Elements;
System.Collections.Generic.List<Element> pdfList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Element>();
for (int i = 0; i < elc.Count; i++)
{
    if(elc[i].Text.Contains("pdf"))
    {
        pdfList.Add(elc[i]);
    }
}
```